# cannot connect UIbutton to interface in xcode3

Tags: xcode

I added a uibutton to the interface  but when trying to connect it to the Controller class, ctrl+dragging to the interface block does nothing. The line simply vanishes, and no connection is made. what is going wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by the Controller class?

Comment: MyViewController.h It is the as in the tutorial at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be connecting the IBAction to the UIButton. When you drag the IBAction connection to the button it should ask you what kind of connection you want to make. I usually choose "touch up inside".

In the connections tab of IB the IBAction should be listed as `changeGreeting:`

Comment: You mean the drag from the "touch up inside" in the inspector to the button in the view?

Comment: No, when you are looking in the inspector make sure the object "files owner" is selected. Then, look in the connections panel (should be somewhere else) and drag the `changeGreeting:` connection onto the button from there.

Answer (score 0):

swami did you give the action method in the .h file? Try declaring the method in .h and its implementation in .m and also make sure that you define the button name in .h file ex: IBOutlet UIButton buttonName;
save it and try doing it by assigning action as touchupinside or any else it should work.

hope it helps you.